Service worker registration failed. Status code: 15" whenever trying to include socket.io client
I'm currently trying to make a chrome extension with socket io client running in the background but it doesn't seem to work.
I read that you need to reference the socket io dist but that doesnt seem to work either.
Html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="node_modules/socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="container">
        <nav class="roomChoice" id="roomChoice">
            <p id="directionLabel">Create or join a link to view Crunchyroll together</p>
            <button id="create">Create</button>
            <button id="join">Join</button>
        </nav>

        <nav class="joinRoom" id="joinRoom">
            <p>Enter room code below</p>
            <input type="text" id="roomInput" placeholder="CODE">
            <button id="joinBtn">Join</button>
        </nav>

        <nav class="createRoom" id="createRoom">
            <p>Below is your room code</p>
            <input type="text" id="codeDisplay" readonly>
        </nav>
    </nav>
    <script src="src/scripts/popup.js"></script>
    <script src="background.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


manifest.json:
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "Minimal Manifest",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "A basic example extension with only required keys",
    "icons": {
      "68" : "src/images/Site_Icon.png"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "content_scripts": [
      {
        "matches": ["https://*.basicdomain.com/*"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
      }
    ]
  }

background.js:
console.log("Background script loaded");


 const socket = io('basicdomain.com');

I've also attached a screenshot of the dist locationsocketio dist

You can't use socket.io inside a service worker because it's based on XMLHttpRequest. Either find a compatible library or use fetch() or use socket.io inside the offscreen document.
